# python optimization if statements

Tags: python, optimization

i would like to optimize this forest of IF statements in python. 
I don't really know for what is about. But i've have to reduce the size of code.

```
def function(pos):
    dg = 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[0][0]][pos[1] + pat2[0][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[1][0]][pos[1] + pat2[1][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[2][0]][pos[1] + pat2[2][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[3][0]][pos[1] + pat2[3][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[4][0]][pos[1] + pat2[4][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[0][0]][pos[1] + pat8[0][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[1][0]][pos[1] + pat8[1][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[2][0]][pos[1] + pat8[2][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[3][0]][pos[1] + pat8[3][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[4][0]][pos[1] + pat8[4][1]] == 2):
            dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[0][0]][pos[1] + pat2[0][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[1][0]][pos[1] + pat2[1][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[2][0]][pos[1] + pat2[2][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[3][0]][pos[1] + pat2[3][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[4][0]][pos[1] + pat2[4][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[0][0]][pos[1] + pat8[0][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[1][0]][pos[1] + pat8[1][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[2][0]][pos[1] + pat8[2][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[3][0]][pos[1] + pat8[3][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[4][0]][pos[1] + pat8[4][1]] == 1):
            dg /= 3
    return dg
```

As you can see, the different lines are very similar, and i'm in search another solution than a while method. 
If you have any idea i'm here.

Thanks you

Thanks you

Comment: You could use a loop?

Comment: Yes i'm allowed to do it but seems a very long loop, don't really know how to change it to a loop, to many if statements for me to really understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing you can do is to create two functions `firstSum` for `pat2` and `secondSum` for `pat8`:

```
def firstSum(board, pat2, pos, i):
    return board[pos[0] + pat2[i][0]][pos[1] + pat2[i][1]] 

def secondSum(board, pat8, pos, i):
    return board[pos[0] + pat8[i][0]][pos[1] + pat8[i][1]]
```

Then you create two functions `multiply` and `divide` to modify `dg`'s value accordingly:

```
def multiply(dg):
    return dg * 2

def divide(dg):
    return dg / 2
```

Then you create a dictionary in which you bind the values from the `if` conditions (`1` and `2` in this case) with the functions above:

```
action = {"2" : multiply, "1" : divide}
```

Finally, you create the loop mentioned in @juvian's answer as follows:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    first = firstSum(board, pat2, pos, i)
    second = secondSum(board, pat8, pos, i)

    dg = action[str(first)](dg)
    dg = action[str(second)](dg)
```

That way you avoid having `if` conditions in your code.

Comment: This solution looks very cool, thanks for your help. Gonna try this

Comment: I think you should try it first and get it to work before accepting. Feel free to ask any questions or any issues with this answer.

Comment: be careful that if there are values other than 1 or 2, will throw error. maybe use a defaultdict with a function to do nothing as default value

Answer (score 1):

A first step would be to take make a loop from 0 to 4 to avoid many repeated ifs for different indexes:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[i][0]][pos[1] + pat2[i][1]] == 2):
        dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[i][0]][pos[1] + pat8[i][1]] == 2):
        dg *= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat2[i][0]][pos[1] + pat2[i][1]] == 1):
        dg /= 2
    if (board[pos[0] + pat8[i][0]][pos[1] + pat8[i][1]] == 1):
        dg /= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `pos`, `pat2[i]` and `pat8[i]` are all supposed to be pairs, doesn't this just reduce to:

```
def function(pos):
  pos0, pos1 = pos
  dg = 2
  for i in range(5):
    for pat0, pat1 in (pat2[i], pat8[i]):
      v = board[pos0 + pat0][pos1 + pat1]
      if v == 2:
        db *= 2
      elif v == 1:
        db /= 3
  return db
```